# SPF Records for QuickBooks Online

Tags: spf, quickbooks

QuickBooks online sends email from the email address listed on the account. This is always going to be the email address of the business rather than an email address that Intuit have permission to send from.

How can I make sure that my emails from QuickBooks online don't get marked as spam?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intuit have published a list of mailservers that they use to send email from QuickBooks online. It can be found [here](https://community.intuit.com/articles/1145633).

An SPF record generated from that list as of 31/8/2013 is as follows:

```
ip4:206.154.105.160/27 ip4:199.16.139.16/28 ip4:206.108.40.0/25
```

This can be inserted into the SPF record for your domain in order to improve deliverability of your email.

Comment: This answer may have been a good one years ago, but is currently not as useful/applicable/right.  First, the referenced page is no longer there.  I did find https://community.intuit.com/articles/1145633 ;;; Second, 206.108.40.7/25 is nonsense as a /25 covers .0-.127 or .128-.255 so starting a /25 with .7 seems like a pretty non-standard notation.  Third, just today I encountered an issue with someone using Quickbooks who had mails coming from somewhere within 199.34/16 which is not within the 199.16/16 (much less 199.16..../27) range.  Maybe QuickBooks updated what addresses they use.

Comment: @TOOGAM: Thanks for the notification of the dead link. I'll update the subnet markers as well, as I misunderstood how they worked back then. As for the 199.34/16, do you have the exact address for that? Does the reverse DNS lookup make it look like a mailserver?

Comment: I don't have an official range, and I think that if Intuit is providing a service of sending mails, then they should officially provide a range for people to use (preferably by public, maintained documentation).  However, I am not currently planning to pursue that.  I came across this while professionally serving a client, and I succeeded in my professional tasks without resolving this, so I am left without incentive (nor very compelling interest) to invest in further researching this possibly-changeable information at this time.

Answer (score 3):

As all the servers end in the same domain it can be very easy to do. I just added the following to my SPF record:

```
ptr:intuit.com
```

A quick test to a GMail account shows it works:

```
 Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of <removed> designates 206.108.40.12 as permitted sender) client-ip=206.108.40.12;
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a better option because it's using hostnames instead of IP addresses

http://kb.nexlynx.com/KB/a45/quickbooks-online-spf-record.aspx

```
v=spf1 mx:yourdomain.com a:mailout11.intuit.com a:mailout12.intuit.com a:mailout13.intuit.com a:mailout14.intuit.com a:mailout21.intuit.com a:mailout22.intuit.com a:mailout23.intuit.com a:mailout24.intuit.com a:mailout102.intuit.com a:mailout201.intuit.com a ~all
```

Comment: Only problem with using that system is that you're limited to 10 DNS lookups for an SPF request. If you include all of Intuit's mailservers there then you'd have to specify your own mail servers as IP addresses. Source: http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Common_mistakes

Comment: @MatthewSteeples  You are correct, thanks for alerting that to me.

Comment: Sore voice of experience I'm afraid!

Comment: There is also the limitation of 255 characters, my example above is 264, found that answer here [link](http://kb.nexlynx.com/KB/a45/quickbooks-online-spf-record.aspx)